# AsyncTasks + Fragment Retain or AsyncLoaders

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider

What will be the best option to interact with the Database, use SQliteOpenHelper with AsyncTasks and Fragment Retain to survive during configuration changes or use an AsyncLoader but in this case i'll have to implement a Content Provider.

Some Pros of using Content Provider i can think:

- Better abstraction of the data model
- Loaders benefits
- Adaptable to future changes
- IPC and Security
- Cursor updates when data changes

Cons

- More difficult to implement
- Some benefits are not useful if share data with other apps its not needed

By the points above i think AsyncLoader and ContentProvider is the best option despite the work it takes to implement but i don't have the enough experience with android to know all the pros and cons. Maybe i could be missing something

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are a beginner or just started out with Android recently, I would recommend `CursorLoader` and `ContentProvider` simply because it is pretty much the only well-documented approach you'll find online.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks Alex, i will implement the CursorLoader and ContentProvider way, i've knowledge in programming and design patterns but in Android I'm just starting out, i've read your blog and it's really good to learn some android patterns we can use. In AsyncTasks a retain fragment is the best option right ? I can attach the activity and detach it from the asyncTask when a configuration change happens but it isn't the best way nowadays i guess.